# In CodedUI how to click menu Items from any page without capturing UIMap of Menu in everypage?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, mstest, coded-ui-tests

We have 5 pages in our website with below fixed menu.

```
HOME | MENU1      | MENU2
     | SUBMENU1.1 | SUBMENU2.1
                  | SUBMENU2.2
```

I have captured UIMap of Homepage and am able to navigate to any of the page from Homepage. But how do i click on menu Items when I am not on Homepage. I don't want to capture UIMaps of Menu for everypage.

---

**Solution:** 
Taking a hint from yonitdm's suggestion below I created a separate UIMap having navigation menu items only. In that UImap I stripped all the search/filter properties from all controls having *Window Title* and other non common properties. So now i have a generic UIMap of navigation menu working for all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the menu from the homepage to one of the other pages and see what the difference is. Strip that out of the [properties list in the UIMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269459%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and you'll have generic menu items.

Places to look: Window Titles, Control definition, href. Make sure to check both the filter properties and the search properties.

You can test this on a few pages by using "locate control" in the UImap to make sure coded ui can still find the menu items.

Comment: Good idea.. I will try to remove menu item properties from Homepage which are specific to homepage only and then see if I can locate those items from other pages. Will give it a try and let you know on monday.

Answer (score 0):

You could try going directly to the hyperlinks by using

```
 NavigateToUrl()
```

Comment: Can't do. I am trying to create a test framework, and don't want it to break in future if url changes.